# Open Cart inside Wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, iis, opencart

I have an **existing IIS Server** on which:
I have an **existing open cart website inside a directory** { example-url : *abcd.com/open-cart-website/* }.
Now I have **updated my main website with wordpress** website. So now I have **wordpress installed in abcd.com/** & **opencart in abcd.com/open-cart-website/** .
I **cant change opencart website url** at all because it has existing PPC & SEO.
Index page of Opencart is accessible but none of the other page on open cart website is accesible, instead an error from wordpress is shown with error 404.
***Need help!!!***

Comment: have you updated config files of opencart?

Comment: what updation should be made to open cart config?

Comment: define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://abcd.com/open-cart-website/'); have you updated this in both config files

Comment: I did this in opencart config file. Am I supposed to do the same with wordpress config file?

Comment: No i guess. is it working now?

Comment: No. not by that method.

Comment: Okay :) Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote down some rules in web.config of my wordpress website and now both are working.
Here are the rules, may be it helps some other developer.

```
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/open-cart-website/*" ignoreCase="false" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Main Rule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([^?]*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="false" pattern="^/open-cart-website/*$"  ignoreCase="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```